# Android Camera setExposureCompensation(int value) not working as expected

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I'm developing an app using opencv library on android, the default camera class *JavaCameraView* uses the deprecated library android.hardware.Camera

I want to **control the exposure level manually** and disable camera auto exposure.

The only way I found to disable it was setting ***setAutoExposureLock*** to **true**, but it also makes *setExposureCompensation* useless.

Moreover, ***getExposureCompensation()* always** returns **0** even in autoexposure mode, if I modify it with *setExposureCompensation(int value)* it returns the value I set, but the camera preview is still the same.

I found out that setting **several times *setExposureCompensation* to its maximum works**, more or less, it slowly changes the camera preview exposure to its maximum exposure... but it doesn't make any sense.

Here's the code:

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setAutoExposureLock(false);
    parameters.setExposureCompensation(parameters.getMaxExposureCompensation());
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

By the way, my device is a Moto G (Android 6.0), exposure compensation levels go from -12 to 12, exposure step 0.166667.

I would like to be able to put a particular level of exposure.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution.

Leaving *setAutoExposureLock* to false and setting the exposure in every *onPreviewFrame()* works fine.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setExposureCompensation(exposure);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

I hope this helps someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to set exposure:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setExposureCompensation(-10);
params.setAutoExposureLock(true);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

I set `setExposureCompensation()` first, then `setAutoExposureLock` to `true` and then put this code in `initializeCamera()`, no need to put it in `onPreviewFrame()`.